# PixiJS Random Rotation & Declining Speed

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to get a simple random "rotation" based on the angle property, and would like to achieve the following.

- Random Rotation, say "rotate" to 500 degrees
- Start with a high speed and when getting nearer to the "rotated" degrees, lower the "rotating" speed so that the stop is not instant.

I put a basic concept of what I am trying to achieve on this link:
https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/yalRPEN~6tg3seIHq5hbI

In the animate function, if I put the let degrees = 2000; as a Math.Random value it screws up the animation as it seems that this animate function is called numerous times?

Also, I tried using the speed property which would start off with a high value and starts to get lower with "rotations", but it seems to do nothing? Also tried using animationSpeed since I am using the angle property to change degrees, but I see no speed difference.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try `bunny.angle += Math.max(-10, Math.min(10, (degrees - bunny.angle) * .01));`

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this makes sense but the suggestion by Afron below is easier to understand. Do you know how to determine when the animation / rotation ends?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to change the angle and not the speed. Something like this:

```
var angleStep = 40;
let rotateSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300)

function animate() {
    bunny.angle += angleStep;

    angleStep = angleStep - angleStep/rotateSpeed;

    if ((angleStep.toFixed(1) <= 0.0)) {
        console.log("stopped rotation")
        bunny.angle = bunny.angle;
        return bunny.angle;
    } else {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Afron, this makes it easy to understand. One thing I am struggling with now is to determine when the "rotation" angle would have finished? I did an if statement to check the angleStep is less than 0 however its not getting hit and from what I can see it keeps going to a negative value. Any way I can call a function/do some logic once the rotation ends?

Comment: The problem is that you are checking if the angle is 0.0 (angleStep <= 0.0)
Since the angle is something like 0.000023441791789347884, it will always be a little bit higher. In that case this should do the trick: (angleStep.toFixed(1) <= 0.0)

Comment: yes I got that, sorry I was not clear in my message. Implementing the if statement based on how you suggested would still make the if statement hit more than once.. could possibly hit 400 times. What I am trying to understand/identify is the proper way to stop the rotation and perform logic/code post the rotation. Is the correct way to check if the animation is done by actually implementing the if statement I mentioned or is there a better approach?

Comment: Well, one way is to stop calling the requestAnimationFrame once the the condition is  met. I will edit my answer so you see what i mean, otherwise i will only make it complicated trying to explain!

Comment: Ok understood. Was thinking if it was possible to have the animate return a value once the animation is complete.. "let angle = animate(rotateSpeed);" .. but as it is, the debugger is hit before the rotation is completed. I have updated my example so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but if you want the debugger to fire after the animation is complete, you can insert the debugger inside a function, and call that function as the callback.

Comment: Thanks Afron for your help